# Can a Technomancer with Biowire thread a memorized Skillsoft?

Tags: shadowrun-sr4, technomancer

I'm playing a Technomancer in a SR4 game and since every other players is bored when I spend more than 5 minutes hacking (which I understand but someone has to gather intel), I decided to give a try to fight stuff. But my kung fu is pretty lame, so I bought the echo Biowire (Unwired p.145):

> By acquiring the Biowire echo, the technomancer receives the
>   ability to modulate the neuroelectrical and neuromuscular network
>   of his body such that it can work similarly to a skillwire cyberware
>   system (p. 335, SR4). In game terms, it operates with a rating equal
>   to the submersion grade of the technomancer. In all other regards,
>   it follows the basic rules for skillwire systems. However, since technomancers are unable to process active skillsoft programs, they have
>   to convert them into complex form–like programs to interpret and
>   process them in their “language” by **emulation**.

Emulation (Unwired p.149):

> Technomancers with the Biowire echo can use threading to
>   convert skillsofts (in storage accessible to the technomancer) into complex
>   forms that their neuromuscular system can process. To set up the
>   emulator, the technomancer makes a Threading (skillsoft rating) Test.
>   If the program contains other program ratings, raise the threshold by
>   the number of program options or rating points. If he succeeds, he has
>   converted the program into a complex form. He can now either sustain
>   the program as a normal threaded complex form of the same rating
>   or **memorize the skillsoft as a complex form** by paying an amount of
>   Karma equal to the rating (+1 for any program option or program
>   option rating).

Another Technomancers' interesting ability is Threading (SR4A P.240)):

> Technomancers have the ability to improvise Complex Forms that they do not know on the fly, or **increase the rating of a complex form they do know**.

Hence the question: if I memorize a SkillSoft as a complex form, can I improve it with threading ? What is its maximum rating ?

Comment: Interesting question; it hasn't come up in my game but off-hand I'd say it's permissible to improve a complex form like that with threading. As far as the maximum rating, I believe that SkillSofts have a hard cap, and CF ones would still function with that limit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### No: You Cannot Thread a Biowire Echo

At the end of the passage you listed for **Emulation** from pg.149 of *Unwired*.  It is literally the sentence after what you quoted ends.  Quote below, *emphasis mine*

> Memorized Complex Forms emulating skillsofts are
>   limited to the rating of the original skillsoft and *cannot be improved*
>   either by threading or Karma-expenditure.

---

**But let's play Matrix's Advocate**

If your GM ignores this, then consider the SkillSoft rules below (SR4-A, pg342)

> **Activesofts** replicate skills that require physical activity,
>   including all Combat, Physical, Social, Technical, and Vehicle
>   skills (but not Magic or Resonance skills). Recording and programming
>   physical skills is more difficult, so Activesofts are limited in rating.
>   Activesofts must be accessed with a skillwire system (p. 342); the rating
>   of the activesoft is limited by the skillwire system’s rating.
>
> **Skillwires** are a system of neuromuscular controllers
>   placed alongside the body’s natural nervous system to override
>   muscular movement. Skillwire systems allow the use of activesofts
>   (p. 331) with a rating up to the skillwire rating. A skillwire system
>   can handle a number of skillsofts with a total rating equal to its own
>   rating x 2. Changing the current selection of skillsofts takes one
>   Simple Action.
>
> **Threading**: ...No threaded complex form can have a rating greater than
>   twice the technomancer’s Resonance.

So if you are allowed to thread it, the maximum rating would be the lowest value between your Submersion grade or your Resonance x2

Comment: Well damn, I was answering the exact opposite, but it seems you're right.

Comment: For some reason I don't have that sentence in my book...maybe an errata?

Comment: I think I have a second printing for what it's worth, but it's in the Emulation paragraph in the main text of my copy.

Comment: I have a french version, which is obviously printed several months later and usually get the original erratas, and this sentence isn't in it, neither it is in the digital copy I use to reference it here. It is, though, present in [this errata](http://cdn.shadowruntabletop.com/wp-content/uploads/Downloads/unwired_errata_v1.pdf), you may want to add it to your answer.

Comment: There was a second printing of most SR4 supplement after the 20th anniversary edition, with most erratas implemented